# Keyboard Dismisses Automatically After Typing or Removing One Character

Tags: flutter, dart, listview

I'm encountering an issue in my Flutter app where the keyboard dismisses automatically after typing or removing just one character in a TextFormField. I have a ListView.builder with Dismissible widgets containing TextFormFields. However, whenever I type or remove a character in the TextFormField, the keyboard dismisses unexpectedly.

My code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:r6stats/scanner_result.dart';

class PlayerEditor extends StatefulWidget {
  const PlayerEditor({super.key, required this.playerNames});

  final List<String> playerNames;

  @override
  State<PlayerEditor> createState() => _PlayerEditorState();
}

class _PlayerEditorState extends State<PlayerEditor> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<String> players = widget.playerNames;

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Edit Players"),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).push(
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => ScannerResult(playerNames: players),
                  ),
                );
              },
              icon: const Icon(Icons.check))
        ],
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: players.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) => Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
          child: Dismissible(
            key: UniqueKey(),
            direction: DismissDirection.startToEnd,
            onDismissed: (direction) {
              final playerName = players[index];
              ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                content: Text("${players[index]} dismissed"),
                action: SnackBarAction(
                  label: 'UNDO',
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      players.insert(index, playerName);
                    });
                  },
                ),
              ));
              setState(() {
                players.removeAt(index);
              });
            },
            background: Container(
              color: Colors.red,
              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0),
              child: const Icon(Icons.delete, color: Colors.white),
            ),
            child: ListTile(
              tileColor: const Color.fromRGBO(194, 194, 194, 100),
              shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  side: BorderSide(color: Colors.black, width: 1)),
              title: TextFormField(
                initialValue: players[index],
                onChanged: (newValue) {
                  setState(() {
                    players[index] = newValue;
                  });
                },
                style: Theme.of(context)
                    .textTheme
                    .titleMedium!
                    .copyWith(color: Colors.black),
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  border: InputBorder.none,
                  focusedBorder: InputBorder.none,
                  hintText: 'Enter player name',
                ),
              ),
              titleTextStyle: Theme.of(context)
                  .textTheme
                  .titleMedium!
                  .copyWith(color: Colors.black),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I've tried using GlobalKey for the ListView.builder and UniqueKey for each Dismissible widget, but the issue persists. How can I prevent the keyboard from dismissing automatically after typing or removing a character?

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Why are you calling setState for every character?

Comment: @RandalSchwartz thanks for the feedback. My issue with onSubmit is that if the user goes to the next page without tapping the done/check mark on their keyboard the changes don't take effect.

Answer (score 0):

I think there might be two problems with your code.

1. Since you are changing the list of players, and you can not change the value of `widget.playerNames`, you must copy the List items. So, do this:

```
List<String> players = [...widget.playerNames];
```

2. You don't need to use `setState` in your `onChanged` method.

Comment: Thank you that solved it! I want to add that I had the players list inside the build method and that caused the list to reset, so I moved it outside using late and initState.

Comment: Oh! you are right! I didn't pay attention to other `setState`s in your code and the list inside build method. :) Glad you found the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I try to fix the two issues here, `1.` Your playerNames list is a final list which is not okay to modify. `2.` I removed the setState from your textFormField that I may cause the problem of keyboard dismisses.automatically.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:r6stats/scanner_result.dart';

class PlayerEditor extends StatefulWidget {
  const PlayerEditor({super.key, required this.playerNames});

  final List<String> playerNames;

  @override
  State<PlayerEditor> createState() => _PlayerEditorState();
}

class _PlayerEditorState extends State<PlayerEditor> {
  
  List<String> players = [];
  
    @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    players = List<String>.from(widget.playerNames);
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Edit Players"),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).push(
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => ScannerResult(playerNames: players),
                  ),
                );
              },
              icon: const Icon(Icons.check))
        ],
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: players.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) => Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
          child: Dismissible(
            key: UniqueKey(),
            direction: DismissDirection.startToEnd,
            onDismissed: (direction) {
              final playerName = players[index];
              ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                content: Text("${players[index]} dismissed"),
                action: SnackBarAction(
                  label: 'UNDO',
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      players.insert(index, playerName);
                    });
                  },
                ),
              ));
              setState(() {
                players.removeAt(index);
              });
            },
            background: Container(
              color: Colors.red,
              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0),
              child: const Icon(Icons.delete, color: Colors.white),
            ),
            child: ListTile(
              tileColor: const Color.fromRGBO(194, 194, 194, 100),
              shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  side: BorderSide(color: Colors.black, width: 1)),
              title: TextFormField(
                initialValue: players[index],
                onChanged: (newValue) {
                  players[index] = newValue;
                },
                style: Theme.of(context)
                    .textTheme
                    .titleMedium!
                    .copyWith(color: Colors.black),
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  border: InputBorder.none,
                  focusedBorder: InputBorder.none,
                  hintText: 'Enter player name',
                ),
              ),
              titleTextStyle: Theme.of(context)
                  .textTheme
                  .titleMedium!
                  .copyWith(color: Colors.black),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```